# Reshape dataframe type. GroupBy or pivot table or for i in?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe which looks like the below one.

[image]

I'd like to convert to below table type. Pivot? For i in ?

[image]

Any advice in getting this done.

Comment: please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. But since it's your first time, also check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your data because of the way you posted it (please don't do that again) but try something along this, using `pd.pivot_table`:

```
import pandas as pd
new = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['city','class','sort'],columns='month', values ='amount', aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: Thank you. And next time, I will post the type of code source!!